# Whats the difference between functions.database() and admin.database()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using firebase admin and firebase functions on my javascript server backend code, and i cant seem to figure out whats the difference between the fucntions and the admin database reference.
i can use both of them like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


admin.database.ref('reference');
functions.database.ref('reference');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The firebase-functions library is used only to declare [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) triggers for deployment with the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli).

The firebase-admin library is the [Firebase Admin SDK for node](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node), and it's a collection of APIs to interact with Firebase and Google Cloud products.  It doesn't  deal with Cloud Functions at all, though you might use it in a Cloud Function.

When you write `functions.database.ref('reference')`, you are in the process of [building](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder) a [Realtime Database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).  It doesn't do anything until you complete the declaration and export the function so the Firebase CLI can find and deploy it.  I suggest reading the linked documentation in detail to figure out how that works.

When you write `admin.database().ref('reference')`, you are creating a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) object that points to a location in Realtime Database.  You would use this to [read and write the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).